# How to prove that $h(x):=\int_a^bg(t-x)f(t)dt$ is Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions

Assume that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is Lipschitz continuous. Now define
$$
h(x):=\int_a^b g(t-x)f(t)dt.
$$
I want to show that $h$ is Lipschitz continuous.

**My attempt of proof is:**

Since $g$ is Lipschitz continuous, then there exists $K>0$ such that
$$|g(x)-g(y)|\leq K |x-y|.$$
In particular we have
\begin{eqnarray}
|g(t-x)-g(t-y)|\leq K |t-x-(t-y)|=K|x-y| \qquad \qquad (1)
\end{eqnarray}
and multiplying by $|f(t)|$ we obtain
$$\big|g(t-x)-g(t-y)\big|\big|f(t)\big| = \big|\left[g(t-x)-g(t-y)\right] f(t)\big|\leq K |f(t)||x-y|$$
Since $g$ is also continuous then $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|h(x)-h(y)\right| &=& \left|\int_a^b g(t-x)f(t)dt-\int_a^b g(t-y)f(t)dt\right| \\
&=& \bigg|\int_a^b\left[g(t-x)-g(t-y)\right] f(t)dt\bigg| \\
&\leq & \int_a^b \big|\left[g(t-x)-g(t-y)\right] f(t)\big|dt\\
&\leq & \int_a^b K |f(t)||x-y|dt\\
&=& \mathcal K|x-y|
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\mathcal K= K\int_a^bf(t)dt$ is a real constant. Hence $h$ is Lipschitz continuous. $\blacksquare$

My concern is about the use of inequality (1). I am not sure if I can do that. Do I need to specify the value of $t$? For example, mentioning that $t\in[a,b]$.

If you have some advice and feedback about this proof (maybe it is incorrect), I would appreciate it. Thanks.

**Edit:** Changed "$K\in \mathbb R$" for $K>0$ in the first line.

Comment: Your proof is fine. However, you should $k>0$ and $t \in [a,b]$ which you do not know the behaviour of $f$ outside the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Using (1) is not an issue since it holds for **any** $x,y$ you can replace by $t-x,t-y$.

Comment: @MrProof So in the definition of Lipschitz continuity $K$ must be a nonnegative number? In this book https://www.jirka.org/ra/realanal.pdf page 128, the author considers $K\in \mathbb R$ in the definition of Lipschitz continuity. Is this also correct?

Comment: @learningmaths It’s easy to see that this is wrong, what is gay is negative?

Comment: I get it now! Thanks MrProof! (I think you meant: "if $K<0$?") Also @copper.hat, thanks for the feedback.